# Selenium Excel VBA

Tags: vba, selenium

I can find no way to execute JavaScript with VBA with SeleniumBasic where I pass a parameter to the function. It works fine with a static variable. And I find no solution with exhaustive web search. Can you direct me to a resource to resolve the issue? I am using Excel 2007. I can use the JavaScript successfully with VB.NET.

Comment: May I ask why you want to use VBA instead of VB.NET? If you're looking to write data into Excel you can do that with VB.NET as well. You can do everything in VB.NET that you can do in VBA plus you get to use a way better IDE for development. If you need an example to get you started I'll be more than happy to provide one for you.

Comment: It isn't a question of Excel VBA or .Net, apparently Seleniumbasic supports both.  What it apparently does not support is javascript.  I'd never heard of Seleniumbasic and I'd been using various flavors of Basic since 1982 so I looked at it.  It only supports VB Script, however it states that it supports all of Selenium 2.x.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I have applications in both Excel and VB.NET. Except VBA doesn't accept the same syntax as VB.NET for executing javascript where a variable is passed. Here is the current state:Following works in both VB.NET and VBA with static text
driver.ExecuteScript ("document.getElementById('ctl00_Content_lblSepID').innerHTML = 'new';")

Following works in VB.NET but not VBA where argument is passed to javascript
driver.ExecuteScript ("document.getElementById('ctl00_Content_lblSepID').innerHTML = (arguments[0]);", SepName)

Comment: I would not need Excel if I knew how to reference a library at run time. The app takes information from a licensed program library. And mine is an old version. Users would need to load their library.

Comment: You can execute js through selenium basic. What is lacking here is an [MCVE]